# DataTable export to excel is not working

Tags: jquery, datatables, export-to-excel

I need my datatables to export the data to an excel file,but i am trying to use the example provided by the datatables.net.But my datatable is not responding to that functionality. I am posting my code here :

```java
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/css/dataTables.tableTools.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/css/metallic.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/css/jquery-ui.css">

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/js/zebra_datepicker.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/js/dataTables.tableTools.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/js/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
```

```js
$('#mainTable').dataTable({
    dom: 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
    tableTools: {
       "sSwfPath": "../swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"
    },
    "scrollY": 300,
    "scrollCollapse": true,
    "jQueryUI": true,
    "aaSorting": [],
});
```

Somebody help me ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/Lw5npvyd/

I have made this worked before by downloading the swf object and referencing the sswfpath to that location.

```
    Please check the fiddle and change the "sSwfPath"
 with the location of the downloaded
 copy_csv_xls_pdf shockwave flash object.
```

You can download the swf file from https://github.com/DataTables/TableTools/blob/master/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf

Answer (score 0):

```js
tableTools: {
    "sSwfPath": "../swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",
    "aButtons": [
                {
                   'sExtends':'xls',
                    "sFileName": "*.xls"
                },
                'csv','pdf','copy','print'
    ]
},
```

Comment: A brief explanation about why this should work could be useful ..:)

Comment: can anyone help me in this regard i really can not understand why it is not working

Comment: only the print button is coming

Comment: try changing the dom to   "dom": 'T<"clear"><"H"lfr>t<"F"ip>'